# How to collect docs in order in collect() method of a custom aggregator?

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I am developing a custom aggregator using ES 1.3.4. It extends from `NumericMetricsAggregator.MultiValue` class. Its code structure closely resembles that of the `Stats` aggregator. For my requirements, I need the doc Ids to be received in ascending order in the overridden `collect()` method. For most queries, I do get the doc Ids in ascending order. Interestingly for `bool` `should` queries having multiple clauses, I get doc Ids in descending order! How can I fix this? Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the same question on github and got the answer which worked for me. Here's the solution:

> You can call aggregationContext.ensureScoreDocsInOrder(); to make sure
>   that docs are going to come in order, have a look for instance at
>   ReverseNestedAggregator which uses this method.
>
> Queries are indeed allowed to emit documents out-of-order if allowed
>   to do so and if it makes things faster. I believe the only case when
>   it happens today is when you get Lucene's BooleanScorer which is used
>   for top-level disjunctions, so your observation makes sense.

Link to the issue: https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/8216